# how to protect the filename extension in inc file?

Tags: php, drupal

From a book

> A common convention is to use .inc for all include files. However,
>   this potentially exposes you to a major security risk because most
>   servers treat .inc files as plain text. Let’s say an include file
>   contains the username and password to your database, and you store the
>   file with an .inc filename extension within your website’s root
>   folder. Anyone who discovers the name of the file can simply type the
>   URL in a browser address bar, and the browser will obligingly display
>   all your secret details!

But i found there are some `.inc` files in the `include` file in a programme eg:`drupal` and some other programmes,why?how they prevent the inc file from being accessed  from the browser?

Comment: Just use a .php extension. Why use .inc?

Comment: I agree with Paul.  In my opinion, the `.inc` extension for PHP includes is a very outdated practice.  You are better off just using a `.php` extension as you lose no functionality and don't have to depend on some server configuration to deny access to those files.  I would bet that book is 5+ years old.

Comment: @drew010 Drupal uses files with that extension. It is normal practice to use that extension with files that are included from a module, or for Drupal files that are included from modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess can be set to not allow web user requests to resources.

[See this link](http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.html)

and in particular the section reading...

```
<Files ~ "\.(inc)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Drupal's case, the protection is in the `.htaccess` file in Drupal's DocumentRoot:

```
# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

secure folder or virtual directory applications will be handful for this issue. for configuring server issues, check: https://serverfault.com/

if you are trying to solve this issue by using php, then **ioncube** or kind of applications will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the web root is a different folder than the application itself. So the web server doesn't provide the access to the application source files, but only to a public folder with styles, images, etc.

Comment: Drupal is normally installed on the web root directory, or a sub-directory of the root directory.

Comment: I thought the question is meant in general, not only related to Drupal. And in general, moving the application sources out of the publicly accessible web root is a common practice.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:drupal], and it is a question about Drupal.

Comment: Okay, didn't notice the tag, sorry.. Apart from that, the question seems related just to php, with Drupal as an example. If my answer gets another downvote, I'll delete it...